# Changing background color of spinner hides dropdown arrow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a spinnder and set its background color to white. The problem is, the arrow's gone. I don't know why. Is there something wrong?

I'm using this code.

```
drivers = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
drivers.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , driverList);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
drivers.setAdapter(adp1);
drivers.setPrompt("Select Driver");
```

Here's my layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Any ideas? I want to retain the white background but the dropdown arrow should show.

Comment: try to give match_parent to its width

Comment: what is "pass" stand for?

Comment: My bad, pasted the wrong line.

Comment: The arrow not display on right side?

Comment: If you set Spinner custom background color then it fill all area included arrow area so it's better to make your custom background with arrow and set as Spinner Background rather than Background Color.

Comment: Refer my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867539/change-spinner-background-color-but-keep-arrow/43759910#43759910

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem wrapping `spinner` by `RelativeLayOut` and using background for `RelativeLayOut`.Then arrow does not disappears.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00" >
            <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set background image (with arrow) instead of `color`.

**Code**

```
drivers.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_img);
```