# Change spinner background color but keep arrow

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I've read several thing about it but I can't find what I need.
I want to keep the grey arrow but I want to remove the horizontal bar from the default style and have a white background. Do you have any idea of how I can do this ?

Here is what I have now (default spinner style) :

[image]

Here is what I want :

[image]

Comment: What do yo mean ? I have created an arrayadapter to fill the data, but now it's more about the style, not the data.

Comment: you need to create custom ArrayAdapter and custom layout file and then inflate the `.xml` file in that adapter class `getView()` method;

Comment: my solution worked or not?

Comment: create an `image` and set that image as `background` of that spinner

Comment: add foreground or background as white

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For the record, I found an easy solution : Wrap your spinner in a relative layout and add an image :

```
 <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/borderbottom_white"<!-- white background with bottom border -->
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"  >
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/postfield_category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:minHeight="0dp" />
        <ImageView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowspinner" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old but can you tell me where to find the arrowspinner drawable?

Comment: Spinner images that come with the Android SDK can be found in <Android SDK folder>\platforms\<version>\data\res\drawable-xhdpi(hdpi,mdpi etc).

Comment: Not the best solution, TAD (below) and CHANDLER (above) are right

Answer (score 108):

I did a little modification based on  @Mansur Khan 's answer.

We don't have to add an ImageView in this case because the spinner already has a triangle arrow. So check the code below:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <Spinner
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_country"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner" -- do we need a background image here?

Comment: Without this it will look like 1st picture.

Comment: Do you have the image cause I cannot find anything like this on the internet?

Comment: bg_spinner is white background, I just added round corner and padding for it. Also pasted in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to change the background color of this spinner to blue? if yes, how can I change it?

Comment: I can see that layout is white now, but it does not have a border

Comment: @VadimKotov  Use a drawable with border to replace the "#FFFFFF" which is the background of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Chandler Thanks, I've already figured it out. I mean that your example screenshots do not correspond to example code.

Answer (score 38):

A simple solution that doesn't require you to create your own drawable for the arrow is to wrap the spinner with a `RelativeLayout`, and set the background color in the `RelativeLayout`, not the spinner:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f00" >
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
yourspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    ((TextView) yourspinner.getSelectedView()).setBackgroundColor(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.your_color));
}
```

and your class should implement OnItemSelectedListener.

Comment: Can you had more details on how to implement this ? Isn't there a way to use only xml and drawable, since it is only style

Comment: If you put using XML then arrow will be disappear if we set back ground color of textview of that xml file. so this is the simplest way to implement. as i have implemented it in many applications.

Comment: Yes, but if we just change the background color , I will have also the horizontal bar with the arrow. I just need the arrow.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15380215/2655804 , in this he/she want to change text color.

Answer (score 3):

Hi instead of wrapping Spinner component around Parent Layouts like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc which increases layout parsing simply create a drawable called spinner_bg.xml under drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_dropdown_arw" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Set spinner_bg as the background of your spinner and it works like charm:

```
<Spinner  
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way without doing **complex layouts** is this:

Use this xml for your spinner background and you are good to go!!!

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/materialBlueGray600" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/materialGray50" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/materialGray50" />
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:gravity="right">
            <bitmap android:antialias="true"  android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_small" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: Showing error in this code

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code of custom spinner. Please check it out and tell me. Not yet I tested this. So please inform me after checking this whether it solves your problem.

```
<Spinner                                
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:textColor="your text color"
    android:textSize="your text size" />
```

Here is the drawable(spinner_background.xml) to create the background of spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="border color" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Edit:**

please check this link which gives you an idea to do.
[Customize spinner background](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57)

OR

you can do something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="spinner background image">

        <Spinner       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:background="@null"/>

        <ImageView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="arrow image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, but what about the arrow ? Is there a way to create the small grey arrow on the bottom right with a <shape> element ?

Comment: please check the edit and check whether your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

below layout will create a background in spinner with desire color drop down arrow

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_shape"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinerComanyName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:entries="@array/spinner_item"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:theme="@style/Spinner"

        />
   </LinearLayout>

   <style name="Spinner">
    <!-- Used for the bottom line when not selected / focused -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- colorControlActivated & colorControlHighlight use the colorAccent          color by default -->
   </style>
```

edit_text_rounded_shape which provide background color and rounded corner

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
         <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
         <stroke android:color="@color/grey"/>
     <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
     android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
  </shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to customise spinners and any other Android controls is to use the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) site and choose the [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/). This will create all the assets you might need, including the "underline". It also generates the XML files that implement the changes.

Once you download the ZIP file from that site, you just copy the images and XML files into your project.

You can then edit the required image files to remove the underline. They are 9-Patch files, called:

- apptheme_spinner_default_holo_light.9.png
- apptheme_spinner_disabled_holo_light.9.png
- apptheme_spinner_focused_holo_light.9.png
- apptheme_spinner_pressed_holo_light.9.png

---

For a more complete explanation of the process, and to see some of the sample XML files, please refer to my related answer:

- [Change colour of small triangle on spinner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911612/383414)

Answer (score 1):

```
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spnLocation"
        android:entries="@array/labelFamily"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_gray"
```

this work for me

Answer (score 1):

Always while working with spinners, buttons and EditTexts and also needing to insert a drawable, I often wrap the element (spinner, EditText etc.) in a FrameLayout. Check an example:

```
<FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <Spinner
                                    android:id="@+id/spinner_component"                                
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/your_rectangle_style"
                                    android:textColor="@color/your_text_color" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="11dp"
                                    android:layout_height="9dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_spinner"
                                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />
                            </FrameLayout>
```

Another important tip is that FrameLayout allows you to set OnClick functions on the drawable, for instance.